# what are the consequences of removing ssh-agent?

Tags: ssh

after the run of the pc a ssh-process has been started. /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/im-launch mate-session

what will happen if the root-user delete the 'ssh-agent' in /usr/bin?
will that damage the os somehow?

Answer (score 1):

First, the file /usr/bin/ssh-agent is placed by the package manager.
DO NOT REMOVE these files using 'rm'. Doing so may break your system quite horribly.
Always remove package-provided files using the package manager.

Here's how you can tell **which package provided a specific file**:

```
 $ dpkg -S /usr/bin/ssh-agent 
 openssh-client: /usr/bin/ssh-agent
```

In this case, the file `/usr/bin/ssh-agent` is provided by the package `openssh-client`

Next, here's how you can tell **the effect of removing that package**. Let's ask apt to simulate the removal:

```
$ apt remove openssh-client --simulate
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome-software-plugin-snap openssh-client snapd ssh-import-id sshfs
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

We can see that on MY system (yours may differ!), removing the `openssh-client` package will also remove `snapd` and `sshfs`. I happen to use snaps, and I happen to use sshfs for some network activities. In my case, removing `openssh-client` would be unwise.

Since your system may differ, you must read the list of proposed removals and make your own decision.

Comment: @ccsann I do not see the relevance of your comment to this answer. Please open a new question for whatever problem you seem to be having.

Answer (score 0):

Answering "what will happen if the root-user delete the 'ssh-agent' in /usr/bin?":

Nothing will happen to programs running `ssh-agent` - they've already read the file into RAM.

The disk blocks of the file won't be returned to free space until all processes that have the file open close it (or terminate).

However, the next time anybody tries to run `ssh-agent`, they'll fail, with

```
walt@fox:~(0)$ ssh-agent
No command 'ssh-agent' found, did you mean:
 Command 'ssh-agent' from package 'openssh-client' (main)
ssh-agent: command not found
walt@fox:~(127)$
```

If invoking `ssh-agent` is built in to your login process, your login process will no longer work, and you'll have a Bad Day/Week.

Comment: which are the programs running 'ssh-agent'?